# Need to sort a table and get the url and share with others which shows the sorted result

Tags: jquery, widget, tablesorter

I have a table which I am sorting on multiple columns (using shift+click) using jquery.tablesorter.combined.js and using saveSort widget 
to save the sort.

is there any way i can sort this in server side and get the url so that I can copy & paste the url and share this result with others via URL ?
Loading this URL should give me the sorted table as it is.

Please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a widget to add the current sort to the hash. It has not be thoroughly tested and does not appear to work in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/545/) because of the inability to set the hash on the inner frame. It does work in a full page demo.

```
/*! Widget: sort2Hash */
;( function( $ ) {
'use strict';
var ts = $.tablesorter || {},
s2h = {
    init : function( c, wo ) {
        var arry, indx, len, column, direction,
            sort = s2h.getSort( c, wo );
        if (sort) {
            arry = sort.split( wo.sort2Hash_separator );
            len = arry.length;
            sort = [];
            for ( indx = 0; indx < len; indx++ ) {
                column = arry[ indx++ ];
                direction = arry[ indx ];
                if ( typeof direction !== 'undefined' ) {
                    sort.push( [ column, direction ] );
                }
            }
            if ( sort.length ) {
                c.sortList = sort;
            }
        }
        c.$table.on( 'sortEnd.sort2hash', function() {
            s2h.setHash( c, wo );
        });
    },
    getTableId : function( c, wo ) {
        return wo.sort2Hash_tableId ||
            c.table.id ||
            'table' + $( 'table' ).index( c.$table );
    },
    getSort : function( c, wo, clean ) {
        // modified original code from http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
        var name = s2h.getTableId( c, wo ).replace( /[\[]/, '\\[' ).replace( /[\]]/, '\\]' ),
            sort = ( new RegExp( '[\\#&]' + name + '=([^&]*)' ) ).exec( window.location.hash );
        if ( sort === null ) {
            return '';
        } else {
            if ( clean ) {
                window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace( '&' + name + '=' + sort[ 1 ], '' );
            }
            return sort[ 1 ];
        }
    },
    setHash : function( c, wo ) {
        var hash, indx,
            arry = [],
            tableId = s2h.getTableId( c, wo ) + '=',
            sort = c.sortList || [],
            len = sort.length;
        if ( len ) {
            s2h.getSort( c, wo, true ); // remove hash
            window.location.hash += ( window.location.hash.length ? '' : wo.sort2Hash_hash ) +
                 '&' + tableId +
                // flatten array, then join with separator
                [].concat.apply( [], sort ).join( wo.sort2Hash_separator );
        }
    }
};

ts.addWidget({
    id: 'sort2Hash',
    options: {
        sort2Hash_hash      : '#', // hash prefix
        sort2Hash_separator : '-', // don't '#' or '=' here
        sort2Hash_tableId   : null // this option > table ID > table index on page
    },
    init: function(table, thisWidget, c, wo) {
        s2h.init( c, wo );
    },
    remove: function(table, c) {
        c.$table.off( 'sortEnd.sort2hash' );
    }
});

})(jQuery);

$(function() {

    $( 'table' ).tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: [ 'zebra', 'sort2Hash' ],
        widgetOptions : {
            // hash prefix
            sort2Hash_hash      : '#',
            // don't '#' or '=' here
            sort2Hash_separator : ',',
            // this option > table ID > table index on page
            sort2Hash_tableId   : null
        }
    });

});
```

I'll include this widget in the next update of my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Comment: Thank you for this awesome widget its working for me well.

Comment: Some issue I see here is when I shift click and select the columns to sort I get a link like this 
http://localhost/test/run.php?pgm=20150714#&resultTable=0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0
now when I delete this string (#&resultTable=0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0) from url and reload the page the same string will get appended to the url,and instead of loading a fresh page the old page is again loading where I have my sorted result .Is it possible to load the page with the given url in case of new page load?

Comment: Also I see that when browser cache is cleared the new page is loading with the given URL with out appending the result table string.Also for my code table header href=javascript:void(0)%s", $colnames[$column]
When I click on the table header, Mozilla is opening a new blank window.
Where as in google chrome this behaviour is not observed.

Comment: Also one more thing I noticed with both browsers(chrome nd firefox) is that 
I copied the URL http://localhost/test/run.php?pgm=20150714#=&resultTable=0,0,1,0,2,0
and pasted in firefox ,where I already have 1 tab opened with 
URL http://localhost/test/run.php?pgm=20150714#=&resultTable=0,0,1,0,3,1 ,the above URL I pasted in new tab also changed to the existing URL (http://localhost/test/run.php?pgm=20150714#=&resultTable=0,0,1,0,3,1)
Is it like in one browser session we can open only one test result?Opening in new tabs is giving 
incorrect result.
Please advice how to proceed on this.

Comment: Please see my comments at https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/962#issuecomment-121676823